# How to toggle hover event for another selector on click?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

[Please take a look at this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nj65w/27/)

Would anyone please tell me how to enable a hover event for the table cells on clicking the button `#edit_mode` and disable it on another click?

```
<button id='enable_mode'>Enable</button>

<table>
  <tbody>
   <tr><td>Package</td><td>1</td></tr>
   <tr><td>Cost</td><td>900</td></tr>
 </tbody>
</table>
```

jQuery:

```
$('#enable_mode').click(function(){
   $(this).text(function(i, text){
          return text === "Enable" ? "Enable" : "Disable";
   })
   var see = $(this).text()
   if($(this).text() == "Enable"){
     hoverme($('table tbody tr td:nth-child(2)'));
   }else{
      ????
   }
});

function hoverme(para) {
$(para).hover(
   function() {
     $(this ).append('<div id="edit">Edit</div>' );
    }, function() {
     $( this ).find('#edit').remove();
   }
  );
}
```

Comment: Do you want to open up a dialog or replace the code with an input field? Several clicks leads to many "edit" divs in your page...

Comment: I don't see any `#edit_mode` there.. Please explain further..

Comment: This may not be relevant, but if you want to add an edit button on hover, why not just add it from the start? By using a simple icon (like a pencil for example), you don't have to worry about the hover state etc., and users will still be able to easily edit the corresponding row.

Comment: @Dreamonic Yes, should be the way to go. No need to worry about the button as well.

Comment: @RedGiant Well, why don't you do it that way then? ;-) If you can, I would just add the edit icon to the row by default. But of course, if you're working for a client and the button is what he requested, you'll have to do it like this. You can always try to convince the client not to, but good luck with that :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might be what you want to achieve: **[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nj65w/33/)**
And here's the corresponding code. HTML and CSS code stays the same, I've just added a few more rows for clarity, and some padding and margin.

**JS:**

```
$('#enable_mode').click(function () {
    //Check the text of the button
    $(this).text(function (i, text) {
        if (text === "Enable") {
            //Enable hover state with events on mouseenter and mouseleaves 
            $("tr").hover(function () {
                //On mouseenter, change background color (= hover state)
                $(this).css("background-color", "#DDD");
            }, function () {
                //On mouseleave, change background color to default
                $(this).css("background-color", "white");
            });
        } else if (text === "Disable") {
            //Remove mouseenter and mouseleave events.
            $("tr").unbind('mouseenter mouseleave');
        }

        //Toggle the text in the button
        return text === "Enable" ? "Disable" : "Enable";
    });
});
```

You can modify this code to do practically anything on hover, including appending things (like you wanted to do).

Answer (score 1):

I have modified your code little bit to achieve your what [**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/64gW5/)

Code:

```
var para = $('table tbody tr td:nth-child(2)');
$('#enable_mode').click(function()
{
   var that = $(this);
   if($(this).text() == "Enable")
   {
     para.bind('mouseover', mouseOver).bind('mouseout', mouseOut);
     that.text("Disable");
   }
   else
   {
     para.unbind('mouseover mouseout');
     that.text("Enable");
   }
});


function mouseOver() {
  $(this).append('<div id="edit">Edit</div>' );
}
function mouseOut() {
  para.find('#edit').remove();
}
```